# Want a pattern for preg_match() for given input according to current situation... PHP

Tags: php, regex

If Decimal separator ( point(.) or comma(,) and thousand separator (comma(,) or point(.)) are present the incoming value should be handled by pattern.
My current code is

```
if (!preg_match('/^((?:(?:\-?[\d' . $thousandSeparator . ']+(?:' . $decimalSeparator . '\d+)?)|\s*))\s*(.*)$/', $value, $matches)) 
{
   throw_error;
}
```

**CASE 1** - 
$decimalSeparator = '.';
$thousandSeparator = ',';

Allowed cases -

- 45,789.45
- 45,789.45 cm
- 789 cm
- 789.45 cm
- 1,789 cm
- 78,789,756.45

Not allowed cases -

- 45.789,78
- 45.789,78 cm
- 78.7.78,78
- 7.8,5
- 7.8 cm

**Case 2** -
$decimalSeparator = ',';
$thousandSeparator = '.';

Allowed cases -

- 45.789,78
- 45.789,78 cm
- 789,45
- 1.789 cm
- 789

Not allowed cases -

- 45,789.45
- 45,789.45 cm
- 789 cm
- 789.45 cm
- 1,789 cm
- 78,789,756.45
- 78,78,78 cm

Note - 'cm' is centimeter which is variable, there can be inch, mm, km, etc. The unit can be present or not, but if it is there, it need to be handled. Now i have put the unit randomly, please not considered unit as it is exact way.

Thanks. :)

Comment: It is not clear for me why `789.45 cm` should be allowed while `7.8 cm` not (for the first case).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Wc9Lf9/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your pattern like this:

```
$units = ['[mck]m', 'inch']; // complete it
$pattern = sprintf('~^-?\d{1,3}(?:[%s]\d{3})*(?:[%s]\d\d)?(?: (?:%s))?$~', $thousandSep, $decimalSep, implode('|', $units));
```

Comment: i like you pattern. Good work :) 
can you tell me what will be the pattern, if we remove the units section from the input, ?
Also changed in your pattern to
`'~^-?\d{1,3}(?:[%s]\d{3})*(?:[%s]\d+)?(?: (?:%s))?$~` , as i want to allow multiple digits after decimal sep.

Comment: @KshitijYelpale: If you don't want the unit part, you need to remove `(?: (?:%s))?` and the last parameter of `sprintf`.